# Creating list from multiple list?

Tags: c#, list

I'm not sure if I'm going about this right.  What I need is after the user creates all of their lines, could be 1 could be 10.  I can calculate the length of those lines, take the zone that line appeared in and add it to a list.

So in the end you have for example

```
Length   Location  
2        1  
4        2  
3        1  
8        1
```

Afterwards I will be adding this data to their respective columns on the oracle server.  Is a list appropriate?  I get an out of bounds error currently on Zone1 and distfinal.  If I just do one line then I get a length calc but an out of bound error on Zone1

```
    List<string> Zone1 = new List<string>();

        private Point p1, p2;
        List<Point> p1List = new List<Point>();
        List<Point> p2List = new List<Point>();

Dictionary<string, int> Void = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Left))
            {
                if (p1.X == 0)
                {
                    p1.X = e.X;
                    p1.Y = e.Y;

                    var color = zoneMap1.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
                    if (color == Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255))
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("Zone 1");
                        Zone1.Add("1");
                    }
                    else if (color == Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0))
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("Zone 2");
                        Zone1.Add("2");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    p2.X = e.X;
                    p2.Y = e.Y;

                    p1List.Add(p1);
                    p2List.Add(p2);     

                    Invalidate();
                    pictureBox1.Refresh();
                    p1.X = 0;
                }
            }
        }


        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Red, 5))
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < p1List.Count; x++)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, p1List[x], p2List[x]);
                }
            }
        }
```

With what I have here, assuming I am going about this correctly, the errors occur with `Void.Add(Zone1[i], distfinal);`

Ultimately I'd like to just create all the lines.  Then use the below button to create the example I gave at the top.

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p1List.Count; i++)
    {
        if (p1List.Count != 0 && p2List.Count != 0)
        {
            dist = (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(p1.X - p1.Y, 2) + Math.Pow(p2.X - p2.Y, 2)));
            int distfinal = (dist % 32);
            Void.Add(Zone1[i], distfinal); 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must first create a line");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are your errors occurring?

Comment: Are you sure that `Zone1` has the same number of items as `p1List`?

Comment: Unless my code is wrong.  I'm not sure of a better way to do this.  Right now the first click created x and adds the zone it was created in.  Then the second click creates y and the line.  Then the 2nd, and so on.  I'd like to have the line created first, then look what zone it was created in, add it and move on to the next line you create but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Your code is missing information about `Zone1` and `Void` . What type is it? How is it defined?

Comment: I updated some things above.  Looks like everything works as long as I make the line in a different location each time.  But I if I put 2 lines in zone 1 or zone 2 then it fails due to the key error.  Not sure how to fix that so I can have multiple entries in each zone.

Answer (score 1):

Well, learned `Tuple` :)

This fixed it.

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(Zone1[i], distfinal));
```